# I cant build and run my project by using dotnet run

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget

I need to run my project without visual studio. So i read it can be run through dotnet command. But when i try to run it like that - using

> dotnet run --project ProjectName.csproj

it pops me these errors .

```
 C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools (>= 2.0.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : warning NU1603: RemotePcWeb depends on Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (>= 2.0.5) but Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.5 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 was resolved.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : warning NU1603: RemotePcWeb depends on Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0) but Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 was resolved.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax (>= 3.2.6)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (>= 2.0.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Newtonsoft.Json (>= 12.0.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'System.Drawing.Common (>= 4.5.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'ZKWeb.System.Drawing (>= 4.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.107\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Value cannot be null. [C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.107\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Parameter name: path [C:\Users\Student\Desktop\RemotePc\RemotePcWeb\RemotePcWeb.csproj]
```

I even run dotnet restore --force , tried another .net core sdk but nothing works. I understand that i need to restore nuget packages but i read dotnet restore should do that, but it didnt. Can somebody help me with this? thanks

Comment: Does build from VS runs ok? It seems you have conflicts with packages versions. Try restore them via VS.

Comment: try running `dotnet restore -v n` to use normal verbosity (the dotnet cli uses minimal by default) to see if anything interesting is logged.